# Django URLconf to URLconf error

Tags: django, mapping

I'm writing my third django app using the tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/ and i'm having trouble mapping an URLconf to another URLconf .

I am going to try and explain my problem as clear as I can .
I have an mysite directory and app directory which I called myapp inside the mysite directory.I am trying to point URLconf of the mysite directory to the URLconf of the myapp directory. Once it's pointed it will execute an 'hello' from the myapp view.py.

The path are :

home/superman/mysite

and my myapp path is

home/superman/mysite/myapp

My urls.conf for mysite is

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   url(r'^polls/',include('mysite.myapp.urls')),
)
```

My view.py inside myapp are

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello")# Create your views here.
```

My urls.py inside myapp are

```
django.conf.urls import patterns,url
from mysite.myapp.views import index

urlpatterns=patterns('',
    url(r'^$',index, name'index')
        )
```

Thank you for helping me

Comment: .I am trying to point URLconf of the mysite directory to the URLconf of the myapp directory. Once it's pointed it will execute an 'hello' from the myapp view.py. thank rohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^polls/',include('myapp.urls', namespace="myapp")),
) 

------------------------------------------------------------
django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns=patterns('myapp.views',
    url(r'^$','index', name='index')
)
```

Comment: The folder is suppose to be called poll in the tutorial but I used myapp instead.Can I use the myapp folder instead?

Comment: yeah just change "polls" to "myapp"

Comment: thank for helping me cathy , i'll try the solution tomorrow as i have to go home

Answer (score 1):

I think you have already done that with line

```
url(r'^polls/',include('mysite.myapp.urls')),
```

in your *mysite/urls.py*. The `index` view will be visible on url `http://yourserver/polls/`

I'm hoping you have fixed python path appropriate so that imports like `from mysite.myapp.views import index` works well. If not you can fix them as `from myapp.views import index`.

And then update the urls.py as

```
url(r'^polls/',include('myapp.urls')),
```